# How to print the contents of crontab with line numbers inside a read command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

Trying to give the users an option to select a line from crontab to remove.
I'm using a read command to get the user's input but I can't properly print the contents of crontab -l with the line numbers.
I can print the contents with line numbers on its own but inside a read command, I can't.

Here is what I'm using:
`read -p "Choose which schedule to remove based on line number:\n$(crontab -l | less -N)\n" removeLine`

I can do:
`crontab -l | less -N`

I've also tried putting the `crontab -l | less -N` inside a variable and using that variable in the read command.

If you have any other suggestions on how better to do this, I'm open to anything. I just need the functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `cat -n` instead of `less -N`?

Comment: Please add as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: or research the shell's oft-neglected `select` function. It may give you the results you want, but hard to tell from your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following. (this solution will only COMMENT the lines NOT remove them, once you are happy with this then you could change it as per your need too)

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Here is the current crontab entries:"
crontab -l
echo ""
echo "Please enter the line number which you want to comment:"
read var

crontab -l | awk -v var="$var" 'FNR==var{$0="#"$0} 1' | crontab -
echo "Printing new cron entries here:"
crontab -l
```

***What does code do?***

- It prints current status of `crontab` to user, so that user can be aware of what are all entries present.
- It prints a message for user(whoever running this script) to enter a line number.
- When user enters a number it saves it into a shell variable named `var`.
- Now it passes that shell variable `var` to `awk`'s code where we again define it as an `awk` variable with name `var`.
- What `awk` code does is: it looks for that specific line and inserts a COMMENT by adding `#` in starting of line and simply prints all lines.
- Now by using command `crontab -` saving new output(manipulated by `awk` command) and it will save it to `crontab` now.

Comment: ++ed for it's completeness as well as user-friendly interface.